# Showing that the positive operator absolute value satisfies a certain inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, positive-definite

Let $H$ be a Hlbert space.  If $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$, then  $|T|=\sqrt{T^*T}$ is called the absolute value of $T$.  And if $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint bounded linear operators, then we say that $A\leq B$ if $B-A$ is a positive operator.  Now show that for any bounded linear operators $S$ and $T$, we have $|S+T|^2\leq2|S|^2+2|T|^2$.

I'm not sure how to proceed.  I tried expanding out $|S+T|^2$ using the definition of absolute value, but it didn't lead anywhere productive.  Note that I'd like to do this without referencing either Borel functional calculus or spectral theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a useful fact to know that there is a parallelogram law for operators in $\mathcal B(H)$. Namely, by expanding you may verify the following equality for $S,T \in \mathcal B(H)$ :
$$
(S+T)^*(S+T) + (S-T)^*(S-T) = 2(S^*S + T^*T)
$$

Note that $|V|^2 = V^*V$ for any operator $V$. This allows us to rewrite the above as $$2(|S|^2 + |T|^2) - |S+T|^2 = |S-T|^2$$

which is a positive operator for fairly obvious reasons, giving the desired inequality.

Further details may be found in Section 3.4 of *Analysis Now*, by Gert K. Pedersen.